# How to create a setup menu screen with steps on AndroidTV

Tags: android, android-tv, google-tv, leanback

I'm just starting to develop an Android TV app.

below video link is the main setting screen of Google TV.

If you look, the top menu is displayed on the left and the sub menu is displayed on the right.

And when the top menu is selected, the submenu on the right moves to the left.

I want to implement a setting page like this, but I can't find it.

Should I use BrowseSupportFragment from Leanback library?

Any help would be appreciated.

You can check the video at the link below

[video link](https://linksharing.samsungcloud.com/qeMQzVal3709)

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide

Answer (score 0):

Since the shared link is expired, I couldn't look at your desired output, but iirc tv settings app is implemented using [GuidedStepSupportFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/leanback/app/GuidedStepSupportFragment). You can refer to [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/guided-step) to find out how to use this Fragment. Also there are some code samples in [Showcase app](https://github.com/android/tv-samples/tree/main/LeanbackShowcase) which might be helpful.
.